# Backprop not getting to layers pytorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor, backpropagation

I had some trouble getting layers in nn.Module to work. I had a bunch of layers that I combined into another layers input. I combined their input this way:

```
previous_out = torch.tensor([previousLayer1Out, previousLayer2Out])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that doing this broke pytorch's connection between this layer and the previous ones. This fixed it:

```
previous_out = torch.cat((previousLayer1Out, previousLayer2Out), 0)
```

I think this is because pytorch keeps track of the inputs/outputs of each layer to perform the back propagation. Before I was creating new tensors, but now I'm concatenating the originals.